# Assign metadata to invoice in Stripe subscriptions

Tags: php, stripe-payments

here is my code to create a subscription:

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $customer->id, //customer id from previous lines after creating customer
        "plan" => 'premium-plan',
        'metadata' => ['user_id' => $userId]
        ));
```

here is my code to update plans:

```
$subscriptionUpdate = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscriptionIdFromDatabase);
    $subscriptionUpdate->plan = 'best-premium-plan';
    $subscriptionUpdate->save();
```

How can I add metadata to an invoice if the user wants to update plans?

if the user wants to update their plan using the second block of code, it will generate an invoice.  how can i assign metadata to that invoice when user changes plans?

Answer (score 0):

Perform an update on the invoice.

```
Invoice::update($invoiceId, ['metadata' => [
    'my_data' => $someVar
]]);
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata